# Kafka not able to connect with Zookeeper in Linux machine

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, confluent-platform

I've been trying to create a producer and consumer in Kafka on linux machine.
I've started an instance of both zookeeper and kafka with the following command.

```
docker run -d \
                --name zookeeper \
                -p 32181:32181 \
                -e ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=32181 \
                confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:4.1.0


docker run -d \
                --name kafka \
                --link zookeeper \
                -p 39092:39092 \
                -e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:32181 \
                -e  KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:39092 \
                    -e KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1 \
                    confluentinc/cp-kafka:4.1.0
```

and kafka is not able to connect with zookeeper.

The above scenario works fine in Mac machine but not in linux.

However, when I start an instance of both zookeeper and kafka with the host command (given below)

```
docker run -d --name zookeeper --network=host -e ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=32181 confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:4.1.0

docker run -d --name kafka --network=host -e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper1:32181 -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:39092 -e KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1 confluentinc/cp-kafka:4.1.0
```

The instances are up and running and kafka is able to connect with zookeeper.

but I donot wish to use host command. can one please share what is the possible solution for the above scenario.

Below is the complete docker logs for zookeeper and kafka.

docker logs kafka

```
# Set environment values if they exist as arguments
if [ $# -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "===> Overriding env params with args ..."
  for var in "$@"
  do
    export "$var"
  done
fi
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'

echo "===> ENV Variables ..."
+ echo '===> ENV Variables ...'
env | sort
===> ENV Variables ...
+ env
+ sort
ALLOW_UNSIGNED=false
COMPONENT=kafka
CONFLUENT_DEB_VERSION=1
CONFLUENT_MAJOR_VERSION=4
CONFLUENT_MINOR_VERSION=1
CONFLUENT_MVN_LABEL=
CONFLUENT_PATCH_VERSION=0
CONFLUENT_PLATFORM_LABEL=
CONFLUENT_VERSION=4.1.0
CUB_CLASSPATH=/etc/confluent/docker/docker-utils.jar
HOME=/root
HOSTNAME=df9a2616ba03
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:39092
KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
KAFKA_VERSION=1.1.0
KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:32181
LANG=C.UTF-8
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/
PYTHON_PIP_VERSION=8.1.2
PYTHON_VERSION=2.7.9-1
SCALA_VERSION=2.11
SHLVL=1
ZOOKEEPER_ENV_ALLOW_UNSIGNED=false
ZOOKEEPER_ENV_COMPONENT=zookeeper
ZOOKEEPER_ENV_CONFLUENT_DEB_VERSION=1
ZOOKEEPER_ENV_CONFLUENT_MAJOR_VERSION=4
ZOOKEEPER_ENV_CONFLUENT_MINOR_VERSION=1
ZOOKEEPER_ENV_CONFLUENT_MVN_LABEL=
ZOOKEEPER_ENV_CONFLUENT_PATCH_VERSION=0
ZOOKEEPER_ENV_CONFLUENT_PLATFORM_LABEL=
ZOOKEEPER_ENV_CONFLUENT_VERSION=4.1.0
ZOOKEEPER_ENV_CUB_CLASSPATH=/etc/confluent/docker/docker-utils.jar
ZOOKEEPER_ENV_KAFKA_VERSION=1.1.0
ZOOKEEPER_ENV_LANG=C.UTF-8
ZOOKEEPER_ENV_PYTHON_PIP_VERSION=8.1.2
ZOOKEEPER_ENV_PYTHON_VERSION=2.7.9-1
ZOOKEEPER_ENV_SCALA_VERSION=2.11
ZOOKEEPER_ENV_ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=32181
ZOOKEEPER_ENV_ZULU_OPENJDK_VERSION=8=8.17.0.3
ZOOKEEPER_NAME=/kafka/zookeeper
ZOOKEEPER_PORT=tcp://172.17.0.2:2181
ZOOKEEPER_PORT_2181_TCP=tcp://172.17.0.2:2181
ZOOKEEPER_PORT_2181_TCP_ADDR=172.17.0.2
ZOOKEEPER_PORT_2181_TCP_PORT=2181
ZOOKEEPER_PORT_2181_TCP_PROTO=tcp
ZOOKEEPER_PORT_2888_TCP=tcp://172.17.0.2:2888
ZOOKEEPER_PORT_2888_TCP_ADDR=172.17.0.2
ZOOKEEPER_PORT_2888_TCP_PORT=2888
ZOOKEEPER_PORT_2888_TCP_PROTO=tcp
ZOOKEEPER_PORT_32181_TCP=tcp://172.17.0.2:32181
ZOOKEEPER_PORT_32181_TCP_ADDR=172.17.0.2
ZOOKEEPER_PORT_32181_TCP_PORT=32181
ZOOKEEPER_PORT_32181_TCP_PROTO=tcp
ZOOKEEPER_PORT_3888_TCP=tcp://172.17.0.2:3888
ZOOKEEPER_PORT_3888_TCP_ADDR=172.17.0.2
ZOOKEEPER_PORT_3888_TCP_PORT=3888
ZOOKEEPER_PORT_3888_TCP_PROTO=tcp
ZULU_OPENJDK_VERSION=8=8.17.0.3
_=/usr/bin/env

echo "===> User"
+ echo '===> User'
===> User
id
+ id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)

echo "===> Configuring ..."
+ echo '===> Configuring ...'
/etc/confluent/docker/configure
===> Configuring ...
+ /etc/confluent/docker/configure

dub ensure KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
+ dub ensure KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
dub ensure KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
+ dub ensure KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS

# By default, LISTENERS is derived from ADVERTISED_LISTENERS by replacing
# hosts with 0.0.0.0. This is good default as it ensures that the broker
# process listens on all ports.
if [[ -z "${KAFKA_LISTENERS-}" ]]
then
  export KAFKA_LISTENERS
  KAFKA_LISTENERS=$(cub listeners "$KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS")
fi
+ [[ -z '' ]]
+ export KAFKA_LISTENERS
cub listeners "$KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS"
++ cub listeners PLAINTEXT://localhost:39092
+ KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:39092

dub path /etc/kafka/ writable
+ dub path /etc/kafka/ writable

if [[ -z "${KAFKA_LOG_DIRS-}" ]]
then
  export KAFKA_LOG_DIRS
  KAFKA_LOG_DIRS="/var/lib/kafka/data"
fi
+ [[ -z '' ]]
+ export KAFKA_LOG_DIRS
+ KAFKA_LOG_DIRS=/var/lib/kafka/data

# advertised.host, advertised.port, host and port are deprecated. Exit if these properties are set.
if [[ -n "${KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT-}" ]]
then
  echo "advertised.port is deprecated. Please use KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS instead."
  exit 1
fi
+ [[ -n '' ]]

if [[ -n "${KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST-}" ]]
then
  echo "advertised.host is deprecated. Please use KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS instead."
  exit 1
fi
+ [[ -n '' ]]

if [[ -n "${KAFKA_HOST-}" ]]
then
  echo "host is deprecated. Please use KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS instead."
  exit 1
fi
+ [[ -n '' ]]

if [[ -n "${KAFKA_PORT-}" ]]
then
  echo "port is deprecated. Please use KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS instead."
  exit 1
fi
+ [[ -n '' ]]

# Set if ADVERTISED_LISTENERS has SSL:// or SASL_SSL:// endpoints.
if [[ $KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS == *"SSL://"* ]]
then
  echo "SSL is enabled."

  dub ensure KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_FILENAME
  export KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION="/etc/kafka/secrets/$KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_FILENAME"
  dub path "$KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION" exists

  dub ensure KAFKA_SSL_KEY_CREDENTIALS
  KAFKA_SSL_KEY_CREDENTIALS_LOCATION="/etc/kafka/secrets/$KAFKA_SSL_KEY_CREDENTIALS"
  dub path "$KAFKA_SSL_KEY_CREDENTIALS_LOCATION" exists
  export KAFKA_SSL_KEY_PASSWORD
  KAFKA_SSL_KEY_PASSWORD=$(cat "$KAFKA_SSL_KEY_CREDENTIALS_LOCATION")

  dub ensure KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_CREDENTIALS
  KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_CREDENTIALS_LOCATION="/etc/kafka/secrets/$KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_CREDENTIALS"
  dub path "$KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_CREDENTIALS_LOCATION" exists
  export KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
  KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=$(cat "$KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_CREDENTIALS_LOCATION")

  if [[ -n "${KAFKA_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH-}" ]] && ( [[ $KAFKA_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH == *"required"* ]] || [[ $KAFKA_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH == *"requested"* ]] )
  then
      dub ensure KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_FILENAME
      export KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION="/etc/kafka/secrets/$KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_FILENAME"
      dub path "$KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION" exists

      dub ensure KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_CREDENTIALS
      KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_CREDENTIALS_LOCATION="/etc/kafka/secrets/$KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_CREDENTIALS"
      dub path "$KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_CREDENTIALS_LOCATION" exists
      export KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD
      KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD=$(cat "$KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_CREDENTIALS_LOCATION")
  fi

fi
+ [[ PLAINTEXT://localhost:39092 == *\S\S\L\:\/\/* ]]

# Set if KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS has SASL_PLAINTEXT:// or SASL_SSL:// endpoints.
if [[ $KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS =~ .*SASL_.*://.* ]]
then
  echo "SASL" is enabled.

  dub ensure KAFKA_OPTS

  if [[ ! $KAFKA_OPTS == *"java.security.auth.login.config"*  ]]
  then
    echo "KAFKA_OPTS should contain 'java.security.auth.login.config' property."
  fi
fi
+ [[ PLAINTEXT://localhost:39092 =~ .*SASL_.*://.* ]]

if [[ -n "${KAFKA_JMX_OPTS-}" ]]
then
  if [[ ! $KAFKA_JMX_OPTS == *"com.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port"*  ]]
  then
    echo "KAFKA_OPTS should contain 'com.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port' property. It is required for accessing the JMX metrics externally."
  fi
fi
+ [[ -n '' ]]

dub template "/etc/confluent/docker/${COMPONENT}.properties.template" "/etc/${COMPONENT}/${COMPONENT}.properties"
+ dub template /etc/confluent/docker/kafka.properties.template /etc/kafka/kafka.properties
dub template "/etc/confluent/docker/log4j.properties.template" "/etc/${COMPONENT}/log4j.properties"
+ dub template /etc/confluent/docker/log4j.properties.template /etc/kafka/log4j.properties
dub template "/etc/confluent/docker/tools-log4j.properties.template" "/etc/${COMPONENT}/tools-log4j.properties"
+ dub template /etc/confluent/docker/tools-log4j.properties.template /etc/kafka/tools-log4j.properties

echo "===> Running preflight checks ... "
+ echo '===> Running preflight checks ... '
/etc/confluent/docker/ensure
+ /etc/confluent/docker/ensure
===> Running preflight checks ... 

===> Check if /var/lib/kafka/data is writable ...
export KAFKA_DATA_DIRS=${KAFKA_DATA_DIRS:-"/var/lib/kafka/data"}
+ export KAFKA_DATA_DIRS=/var/lib/kafka/data
+ KAFKA_DATA_DIRS=/var/lib/kafka/data
echo "===> Check if $KAFKA_DATA_DIRS is writable ..."
+ echo '===> Check if /var/lib/kafka/data is writable ...'
dub path "$KAFKA_DATA_DIRS" writable
+ dub path /var/lib/kafka/data writable
===> Check if Zookeeper is healthy ...

echo "===> Check if Zookeeper is healthy ..."
+ echo '===> Check if Zookeeper is healthy ...'
cub zk-ready "$KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT" "${KAFKA_CUB_ZK_TIMEOUT:-40}"
+ cub zk-ready zookeeper:32181 40
[main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.10-39d3a4f269333c922ed3db283be479f9deacaa0f, built on 03/23/2017 10:13 GMT
[main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:host.name=df9a2616ba03
[main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.version=1.8.0_102
[main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.vendor=Azul Systems, Inc.
[main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/zulu-8-amd64/jre
[main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.class.path=/etc/confluent/docker/docker-utils.jar
[main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
[main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
[main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
[main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:os.name=Linux
[main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:os.arch=amd64
[main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:os.version=4.15.0-46-generic
[main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:user.name=root
[main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:user.home=/root
[main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:user.dir=/
[main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Initiating client connection, connectString=zookeeper:32181 sessionTimeout=40000 watcher=io.confluent.admin.utils.ZookeeperConnectionWatcher@1ddc4ec2
[main-SendThread(zookeeper:32181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server zookeeper/172.17.0.2:32181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
```

using the below commands

```
docker run -d \
                --name zookeeper \
                -p 32181:32181 \
                -e ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=32181 \
                confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:4.1.0


docker run -d \
                --name kafka \
                --link zookeeper \
                -p 39092:39092 \
                -e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:32181 \
                -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:39092 \
                -e KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1 \
                confluentinc/cp-kafka:4.1.0
```

the kafka should have connected with zookeeper as its working in Mac machine but not on linux.

Comment: What do you have against using Compose?

Comment: Note that setting `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:39092` won't allow other containers to connect to that Kafka container

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use `network=host` you need to create and use a docker bridge network: https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#manage-a-user-defined-bridge.

Here is how you could do it:

```
docker network create kafka-network
docker run -d --name zookeeper --network=kafka-network -e ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=32181 confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:4.1.0
docker run -d --name kafka --network=kafka-network -e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:32181 -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:39092 -e KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1 confluentinc/cp-kafka:4.1.0
```